# Error while running gnome-music using jhbuild

Tags: gnome, jhbuild

I'm using jhbuild to build and run gnome-music.
I'm having a successful build but when I run the command

```
   jhbuild run gnome-music
```

I get the following [error](https://pastebin.com/SZ4BRv9d)

```
   One of the errors is 

    1.GstTag was imported without specifying a version first
```

The rest are in the link above.

I'm not sure how to proceed further,can someone help me out?(I'm using Ubuntu 17.04).
I'm following the steps given on:
https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-music

Answer (score 0):

Gst just warns you against not mentioning a version number. Hence, that's not the error.

The error you are facing is regarding Tracker. As you are on Ubuntu distribution, you should know that Ubuntu disables Tracker by default. Hence `jhbuild run gnome-music` refuses to start. [Tracker](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Tracker) is a file-indexing service based on file's metadata.

However, Ubuntu is deciding to enable Tracker by default as many GNOME's core apps relies on it. Read [here](https://community.ubuntu.com/t/install-tracker-by-default-in-18-04-lts/1483).

Enable Tracker and jhbuild will pick it up from the host system.